# Inverse limit of locally compact groups

Tags: topological-groups

If $(G_i,\varphi_i)$ is a inverse system of Hausdorff locally compact groups, then $\varprojlim G_i $ is locally compact?

I have looked for information about it, or any additional condition for the conclusion holds.

I don't know if I added the condition that $G_i$ are compact for almost everywhere it's enough.

Thanks you all for any suggestion or any counterexample

Comment: You write a "direct system" but use the notation for "inverse" limit. Which is it, direct or inverse?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: If it were true, arbitrary countable (unrestricted) direct products of locally compact groups would be locally compact. But actually, a countable direct product $\prod_n G_n$ is locally compact if and only if $G_n$ is compact for all but finitely many $n$. Example: $\mathbf{Z}^\mathbf{N}$ is not locally compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately false.

We can write an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ vector space as an inverse limit of finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487437/vector-space-with-continuum-basis-as-an-inverse-limit-of-finite-dimensional-vect), or PaulFrost's comment below). Now since finite dimensional vector spaces are locally compact, but infinite dimensional spaces aren't (see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/), for instance), we see inverse limits cannot preserve local compactness.

You ask about additional conditions to make the conclusion hold, such as the condition that the $G_n$s are "compact almost everywhere":

If we replace local compactness by compactness, then the theorem becomes true (because of [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem)). In fact, if all but finitely many of the $G_n$s are compact, and the remaining finitely many are merely locally compact, then the inverse limit *is* locally compact (so a version of your "almost everywhere" criterion works!).

To see why, recall $\varprojlim G_n$ is a certain (closed) subgroup of $\prod G_n$. Since the product of *finitely many* locally compact spaces is locally compact (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011614/the-product-of-locally-compact-spaces-is-locally-compact), say), we see $\prod G_n$ is still locally compact, and thus $\varprojlim G_n$, which is a closed subspace, is locally compact too (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289521/closed-subspaces-of-a-locally-compact-space-are-locally-compact)).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Usually one requires the index set to be directed when considering inverse systems. Your $I$ is not. But you can easily modify your example by taking the integers with their standard ordering and $G_n = \mathbb R^n$  and $\varphi_n$ the projections.

Comment: @PaulFrost -- thanks for the correction! Fixed.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks for your answer, is very enlightening for my